# How to bind ResourceDictionary to ViewModelProperty

Tags: mvvm, binding

I have ViewModel for MainWindow with property UriResource. How can I bind this property to ResourceDictionary? I have tried this code:

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="{Binding UriResource}">
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
```

but I get error: All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how my app.settings look like:

```
<Application x:Class="PcgTools.App"
  ...
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="....." />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter"/>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"/>
        <res:Strings
         x:Key="LocStrings"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Probably you need to add x:Key="....."